# How to Find a Lower Bound on the Sum of the Degrees of any Two Distinct Vertices such that the Graph is Connected?

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a graph with $n$ vertices. I want to find a lower bound on the sum
of the degrees of any two distinct vertices such that the graph is connected.

It is best to explore this by analyzing the paths
between two arbitrary vertices $v$ and $w$.

If $v$ and $w$ are not adjacent,
then there must exist a path between them containing some of the other $n-2$ vertices.

I am having issues figuring out how large their degrees need to be to guarantee
this path exists. Any suggestions on this problem?

Comment: The path graph on $n$ vertices has minimal-sum-of-vertex-degree 2: take both edge vertices. The graph is still connected.

Comment: So, to reformulate: let $G$ be a connected graph. You want a lower bound on $\deg(x) + \deg(y)$, as $x$ and $y$ range across all pairs of distinct vertices of $G$?

Comment: @JackM I think he/she means "what is the lowest $r$ such that $\deg(x)+\deg(y)\geq r$ for all pairs of distinct vertices $x,y$ implies $G$ connected?" Or maybe "for an arbitrary pair $x,y$"...